# JAVA: Generics extend two child classes

Tags: java, generics

Say, I have an abstract class A which is extended by child classes B,C & D.
Is there a way to supply an argument that accepts only B & C using generics.

As far as I know, we can combine a class and interface in generics. But can we combine two child classes?

Comment: No. But if you show some code, there might be other ways to do what you want.

Comment: From what little information you gave, I suspect an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: Function polymorphism with different bounds on the generic param?

Comment: combining two  child classes will lead to problem called Diamond problem. https://www.journaldev.com/1775/multiple-inheritance-in-java

Comment: you can set with generic upper or lower bounds where object will operate, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Sure, ill post a detailed code to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, it's not possible. Depending on what the problem that you are trying to solve is, you could do something like this:

```
class Foo {

    public bar(B obj) { fooBar(obj); }
    public bar(C obj) { fooBar(obj); }
    private acceptBAndC(A obj) { /* obj can be B or C */ }

}
```

Then you still share the code between implementations for `B` and `C` while `D`cannot be passed to `fooBar()`.

But IMHO the cleaner solution would be to introduce a new abstract class BOrC that is derived from `A` and have `B` and `C` inherit from that class (but of course not `D`).

But baring sufficient information, I can only guess if that fits your use case.